# Как изменить параметры lineTo?

Tags: javascript, html

Как мне изменить параметры `.lineTo()` у `canvas` по клику?

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("game").getContext('2d');
var button = document.getElementById('myBut');
ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
ctx.lineTo(30, 15);
ctx.stroke();

button.onclick = function() {
  ctx.lineTo(50, 90);
};
```

```html
<canvas id="game" style="background:relative; height:100px; width:400px; border: 1px solid red"></canvas>
<input id="myBut" type="button" value="yeah" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите дорисовать что-то по клику, то вы все сделали правильно, только забыли закрасить новую линию:

```
button.onclick = function() {
  ctx.lineTo(50, 90);
  ctx.stroke(); //< --- вот это я добавил
};
```

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("game").getContext('2d');
var button = document.getElementById('myBut');
ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
ctx.lineTo(30, 15);
ctx.stroke();

button.onclick = function() {
  ctx.lineTo(50, 90);
  ctx.stroke();
};
```

```html
<canvas id="game" style="background:relative; height:100px; width:400px; border: 1px solid red"></canvas>
<input id="myBut" type="button" value="yeah" />
```

Если же вы хотите, чтобы уже нарисованная линия по клику куда-то подвинулась, этого не произойдет. Вам придется весь канвас стереть и заново нарисовать, с уже новым положением линии.

`.lineTo` и любые другие методы рисования на `canvas` совершенно неинтерактивны. Канвас работает по принципу фломастера и белой доски: можно что-то нарисовать, можно что-то стереть, но нельзя что-то выделить и повернуть.

Для решения этой проблемы существует библиотека FabricJS, которая привносит объектный слой в канвас и позволяет манипулировать отдельными объектами - линиями, например. Вот официальный гайд на русском: http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-1_ru/